# ¿Cómo separo una columna de datos en otras columnas según un orden?

Tags: r, rstudio, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente data frame:

```
coches <- data.frame(ID=c(1,3,4,3,8,8,7),fecha=c('06032004', '22012006', '14092007', '25112008', '04122010', '09082018', '01062003'), cliente=c(13, 14, 14, 10, 13, 12, 12),trabajador=c(153, 145, 114, 641, 274, 717, 318),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Como se pueden dar cuenta, en la variable ´fecha´ los datos están juntos. Lo que busco es hacer una columna que separe día, mes y año, dónde en cada columna exista un dato específico con el orden día=2 dígitos, mes=2dígitos y año=4dígitos.

Para que quede algo así

```
coches <- data.frame(ID=c(1), día=c(06), mes=c(03), año=c(2004), cliente=c(13), trabajador=c(153), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

La base con la que cuento tiene 25mil entradas, entonces, me gustaría hacerlo de forma automática. Leí que se puede con el comando split, pero no estoy muy seguro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre usar la función `substring()` que permite extraer caracteres de un vector.

La sintaxis sería la siguiente, con R base:

```
coches$dia<-substring(coches$fecha,1,2)
coches$mes<-substring(coches$fecha,3,4)
coches$año<-substring(coches$fecha,5)
```

La función `substring()` pide como argumentos el vector de donde se extraerá los caracteres, es decir, `coches$fecha` y la posición inicial desde donde empezará, es decir, `1` (para los días) y la posición final que es hasta donde extraerá, es decir, `2` (para los días). Con la misma lógica para el mes y año.

El resultado:

```
> coches
  ID    fecha cliente trabajador dia mes  año
1  1 06032004      13        153  06  03 2004
2  3 22012006      14        145  22  01 2006
3  4 14092007      14        114  14  09 2007
4  3 25112008      10        641  25  11 2008
5  8 04122010      13        274  04  12 2010
6  8 09082018      12        717  09  08 2018
7  7 01062003      12        318  01  06 2003
```

Adicionalmente te adjunto como se podría hacer usando el paquete `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

coches %>% mutate(dia=substring(fecha,1,2),
                  mes=substring(fecha,3,4),
                  año=substring(fecha,5))
```

Y obtendrás el mismo resultado.

```
  ID    fecha cliente trabajador dia mes  año
1  1 06032004      13        153  06  03 2004
2  3 22012006      14        145  22  01 2006
3  4 14092007      14        114  14  09 2007
4  3 25112008      10        641  25  11 2008
5  8 04122010      13        274  04  12 2010
6  8 09082018      12        717  09  08 2018
7  7 01062003      12        318  01  06 2003
```

Comment: Funcionó excelente, muchas gracias.